# Ist "Was ist passiert?" im Aktiv-Perfekt oder im Zustandspassiv-Präsens?

Tags: passive, perfect-tense

Es scheint gegensätzliche Hinweise zu geben. Mir schwirrt der Kopf.

Comment: "Etwas ist passiert" ist (außer es ist vorher "passiert worden", also durch ein  Sieb gestrichen) beim besten Willen kein Passiv.

Comment: Tjäää... könnte man meinen, oder auch nicht ...

Comment: **Sollte** man meinen, wenn man richtig meinen wollen würde.

Comment: Täte man nicht richtig meinen wollen, dann wäre meinen ja auch nicht halb so interessant in der Meinung des meinenden Meiners, meine ich.

Comment: Würde man auf den Satz: "Die Tomaten sind passiert und die Erdbeeren eingekocht" fragen: "Was (von beiden) ist passiert?", dann wäre es wohl das Zustandspassiv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ein Unglück passiert

Ist kein Passiv. Obwohl das Verb "passieren" keine aktive Aktion des Subjekts impliziert, ist die grammatische Form hier eindeutig Aktiv, das Unglück ist das Subjekt.

> Es ist passiert

ist genauso kein Passiv (praktisch derselbe Satz, nur im Perfekt) und

> Was ist passiert?

aus dem gleichen Grund auch nicht.

*passieren* im Sinne von "geschehen" kann (wie "geschehen" selbst, siehe [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:geschehen)) kein Passiv bilden - das würde keinen Sinn ergeben.

*passieren* im Sinne von "vorbeigehen" oder "sieben" allerdings schon: Ich verweise  mal auf das [Institut für deutsche Sprache](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/gramwb.anzeige?v_app=&v_id=10812), dort steht für die erste Bedeutung "kein Passiv möglich").

> Die Marmelade ist passiert worden

und

> Der Elfmeterpunkt wurde vom Spieler auf seinem Lauf zum Tor passiert.

Ist beides Passiv und funktioniert auch so.

Comment: Aahh... "passieren" ist in der Bedeutung von "geschehen" intransitiv, und mit intransitiven Verben kann man grundsätzlich kein Passiv bilden. Groschen gefallen. Herzlichen Dank!

Comment: Ähm, nein. Generell stimmt das nicht. Es gibt durchaus intransitive Verben, die ein subjektloses Vorgangspassiv bilden können - *helfen*, z.B.(*Ihm wird geholfen*). Aber es gibt viele intransitive Verben, bei denen ein Passiv keinen Sinn ergibt.

Comment: Wäh… Ah ja, verstanden.